# Number isn't added to variable in if statement

Tags: batch-file, if-statement, addition

Why doesn't this batch script add the value 5 to the variable `%counter%`?
The script always echo the value 2 with which the variable was initialized.
Outside a if statement the counter works just fine.

```
:start

set /a counter=2
set /p message=Message:

set "spam=%message%"
echo %spam%

if "%message%"=="%spam%" (

set /a counter=%counter% + 5

echo %counter%
)

pause

goto 
start
```

Comment: Just a wild shot but does counter += 5 work?

Comment: Already tried :D But doesn't work :(
Missing operator error comes up

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use delayedexpansion. %counter% is being evaluated outside of the If statement but not inside of it.

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

:start

set /a counter=2 
set /p message=Message:

set "spam=%message%" echo %spam%

if "%message%"=="%spam%" ( set /a counter=%counter% + 5

echo !counter! )

pause

goto start
```

Comment: I'm wondering why it didn't worked before. I already tried to add
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
but I think the rest of the script were a bit different.
Thanks for helping me out!